# How do you integrate $\int e^x \cot(x)dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

> I originally was to evaluate
>   $$
> \int \frac{e^{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}}{\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{x}} \ dx
> $$

So i took $t = \arctan \sqrt{x}$ and then, $\frac1{1+x} = \frac{dt}{dx}$ and $\tan t= \sqrt x$. I plugged this in and ended up with the following integral
$$
\int e^x\cot x\,dx
$$
I tried integration by parts, but couldn't make it work.

I'm only an undergrad. Could you please suggest a method which I can use?

Comment: What makes you think there is an analytical way to integrate in terms of basic functions? Do you possibly mean $\int e^x \cos x dx$ and not $\int e^x \cot x dx$?

Comment: I don't think this has an elementary anti-derivative.  So none of your calculus techniques are going to work.   If this is really a definite integral, tell us the limits.  There might be a trick.

Comment: For what its worth, mathematica says the antiderivative of $e^x\cot(x)$ is $\left(-\frac{2}{5}-\frac{i}{5}\right) e^x \left((1+2 i) \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{i}{2},1;1-\frac{i}{2};e^{2 i x}\right)+e^{2 i x} \,
   _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{i}{2};2-\frac{i}{2};e^{2 i x}\right)\right)$

Comment: i was solving another question and got this by subsitution .So no lmits .Sorry

Comment: Please add some context.. Also is this an xy problem? What is the original problem here? Perhaps you won't even need this integral.

Comment: Is the original this one:
$$\int \frac{e^{\arctan \sqrt x}}{\sqrt x+x\sqrt x}dx?$$

Comment: yeah this is the original

Comment: Well, just note that $\left( \arctan \sqrt x\right)=\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt x+x\sqrt x}$. So the original integral is:
$$2\int e^{\arctan \sqrt x} (\arctan \sqrt x)'dx=2e^{\arctan \sqrt x}+C$$

Comment: isnt it 1/1+{sqrt(x)}^2

Comment: Don't forget about the chain rule.

Comment: @Zacky How did you know? 

Comment: Yeah sorry for disturbing

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I didn't. OP added the original integral in the question body.// No worries ReimannEuler, welcome to MSE :)

Comment: @Zacky I rewrote the question and nominated for reopening, once this happens, please write your suggestion as an answer so the OP can accept it :)

Comment: FYI [this integrating website](https://www.integral-calculator.com) provides in-depth steps for integration problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation is wrong. The integral of $e^x\cdot\cot(x)dx$ is not elementary.

But, the integral you started does have an antiderivative.

$$\frac d{dx}(\arctan(\sqrt x))=\frac12\cdot\frac1{x^{\frac12}+ x^{\frac32}}.$$

So when $t=\arctan(\sqrt x)$, the integral becomes $2e^t dt$, so the final antiderivative is $$2e^t+C=2e^{\arctan(\sqrt x)} + C.$$